# Get notified of disk issue on CentOS 7

Tags: monitoring, centos7

We had a disk issue at ESX level managed by the Datacenter (i.e. not us) and the VMs was unable to use its disk. We saw this in the console/terminal of the ESX for the VM.

```
sd 0:0:0:0: timing out command, waited for 180s
sd 0:0:0:0: timing out command, waited for 180s
sd 0:0:0:0: timing out command, waited for 180s
sd 0:0:0:0: timing out command, waited for 180s
XSF (dm-1) metadata I/O error: block 0x4cb8002 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 1
sd 0:0:0:0: timing out command, waited for 180s
sd 0:0:0:0: timing out command, waited for 180s
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 5615760
Buffer I/O error on device dm-1, logical block 528146
Buffer I/O error on device dm-1, logical block 528147
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 5424481
XSF (dm-1) metadata I/O error: block 0x3d8d61 ("xlog_iodone") error 5 numblks 64
XSF (dm-1) metadata I/O error: block 0x3d8d6a ("xlog_iodone") error 5 numblks 64
```

Is there a way to get notified when this kind of errors raise ?

Maybe it is written to some file that we could monitor content ?

We already have some monitoring tools but we don't know how to get these events

Comment: Take a look in /var/log/messages.

Comment: There is nothing in /var/log/message as disk was stuck, so writing to it was impossible, so nothing was loggued.